# Symbolic Execution/Concolic Testing on OS Kernel

Tags: testing, operating-system, static-analysis, symbolic-execution

Is it possible to run Symbolic execution on Linux Kernel or parts of it?
What about Concolic Testing?
Thanks!

Comment: Concolic=Concrete+Symbolic

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use S2E [1] to analyze binaries in-vivo (within a full software stack). Symbolic execution is S2E's default mode but you can also do concolic testing without much effort.

[1] https://s2e.systems/

Comment: Yes, please check S2E's documentation.

Comment: I communicated with the S2E author. He said that 32-bit is not supported. Because Symbolic Execution is resource intensive whereas 32-bit OS is limiting.

Comment: Your reference just says "You need permission" now.

Comment: @Benni Updated the link